# Select an input generated by cocoon in capybara by name and/or id using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, capybara

I am using cocoon to generate the nested fields in a form but I am having a really hard time selecting the dynamically generated input fields for testing. I assume that the numeric part of the id and name (which are the same by default) is based on the timestamp so I deduce it needs regex to be selected properly.
Appreciate the help in advance.

_form.html.erb

```
   <% if question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
      <p>
        Body: <%= f.text_field :body %>
      </p>
    <p>
      Notes: <%= f.text_field :notes %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Distractors
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="distractors">

    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= link_to_add_association('Add distractor', f, :distractors) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

_distractor_fields.html.erb (as per cocoon conventions)

```
  <div class="nested-fields form-control">
        <%= f.text_field :body, class: "distractor_body" %>
        <%= f.radio_button :correct, 'true', label: true%>
      <%= link_to_remove_association "Delete distractor", f%>
  </div>
```

Relevant cucumber step

```
Then(/^I fill the distractor field with "([^"]*)"$/) do |distractor_body|
  expect(page).to have_css('.distractor_body')#Just to see if it works
  page.should have_css("input", id: 'question[distractors_attributes][[0-9]*][body]')#Fails here
  page.find('#/question\[distractors_attributes\]\[[0-9]*\]\[body\]/', class: '.distractor_body')#Another failing attempt 
  fill_in('.distractor_body', with: distractor_body)
  # Cocoon generated id and name looks like this:
  # question[distractors_attributes][1494262782667][body]
  page.choose('correct')
end
```

Final generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/_settings.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.self-78b811a59aab8664061acba3353fae061b154dec619ec9a7b47714ce5f737bc2.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/foundation_and_overrides.self-ec376498c201e4ea8c1b76053444700483ab234ced1658f9a5e717f9a93fbe32.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/questions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/welcome.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/application.self-0e31f1d30f689436ae56e463f6474eb99704af8bbed5fc320a66ac33afb59c2b.css?body=1" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.core.self-4f457971ba9c2597b09f6a22a24331c38e7279daa591bd61b5bbf28876aa8fc3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.abide.self-679179bf3ee1902bc3fe7da64bbb2b731fa4df4a75901538ba55e7d25286313e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.accordion.self-8d244ceae0d451fcc15789a5e9e36ebed60650c8a9abbf5f9a126b6f327b6154.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.accordionMenu.self-d9a7c97eb11b52fe305e71d2becbdfaf772722f9da6bd56ad24121919d5e43ca.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.drilldown.self-1197ab1398f5a6e188d25902ca65cb079c5c769583801244c456e39aeb484876.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.dropdown.self-c0e613ea4f5cf333f28aa6e97d54dcf6f739b7b95beed9175870525fbb190200.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.dropdownMenu.self-386455a3346e601e0a524f9de7e5146e73ef63055ba5394290f5f9a3a2cb74d7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.equalizer.self-7221ea2a8fba1b3495851e00b58ade3f76ce11a8230ab5cf9ca81a39e7eadd4e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.interchange.self-be09943d6d46443136cd84ffda8b5b8a008db8355c144097949fcaf7d5289a56.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.magellan.self-789eaceb55bd54bd0ed8fea6adf2b18c21464581b0e95eaa8a5aff1130208b2d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.offcanvas.self-9ce0609e0e4404d19bde3425bf63955c74836aa9f0772d9b7e26ab731c1f2e8c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.orbit.self-a127e190c8224d789844ee10a7c4123fe5aef28bc5bf75e9e185b3e098651078.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.responsiveMenu.self-c16f1dc4c3fa8e4881e116d1072642a8f0d53db8725994fd5a32f5cab1a30991.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.responsiveToggle.self-e997867128d1cc2b0268d6d8a0b3d1d4acdd8b18481dbcc50e8c41b06dea77d1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.reveal.self-958c10cf13f0fa316d5753a6c03b7e1c6c76819b5978cefa85df960856744a98.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.slider.self-130c3657134bb131ceec80b3553bfe98731d170c5b6b89506f7aeca0934bf3ab.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.sticky.self-6132d9675d96d8eb9d6426a329ba49a9c70756620079fcf1e9dc0509d710ff3b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.tabs.self-76b83dbeb1a526b713949431c11539c4f15ea95620a32b357452afb4e969778d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.toggler.self-32c8ba5ef7c4612d3cf417a6fb5ff296ee2fc8a1778995f4571c5ca3aed7c1a5.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.tooltip.self-34253627e75f9473117d9e2f269e29eb8871e50679a25ee82736fb52acf0f65a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.box.self-29f7cbc36d64afedbf3295384f579c067ee4a6107059d25041cf9c2ffbdac287.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.keyboard.self-4a273ab1fd2edf1b86d3e772465bff74a28c721021c719eb48de76cf9a220d9c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.mediaQuery.self-f587619a109ff8be49d8eacb95b733d75cbdcc9819a19ce8c2af1be48e65524b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.motion.self-65f3e3cc6f7990ae5a0d964eb90d626e0a5486508a11487145ba14aa4b2a2e78.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.nest.self-10050c8cffe586f45b7cb4570a5aa0d498e566ac981f4e494bd42246b4daafc7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.self-0cb4d35725065a9a79f69d241210298190b5f1e134522d565a872f984e1e26b8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.touch.self-95e098450fe69653246bdfa7f1e7fe7dba15348524771d7b2c54c7c4298fccb5.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.util.triggers.self-4fef1a2bcee50931073341abc76d0747ace3559d818342a079c07c54e27f8add.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.zf.responsiveAccordionTabs.self-1cd003cd23ec70291aa4b3ee3c46097d1fddb74afe524d057af1339b0251bdc9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation.self-5ecf2f4d83e6260dabd6ec48e76d8ddebccf956563f34072221bf960d3b8c255.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/cocoon.self-6874ad698cefd21cc1119b773550f61b5c1a60396460f015222af59293affe80.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-5454023407ffec0d29137c7110917e1e745525ae9afbc05f52104c4cd6597429.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-6e0514260c1aa76eaf252412ce74e63f68819fd19bf740595f592c5ba4c36537.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/questions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/welcome.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-c9d32bb43ab90153f07e848d3f326b7933d8ef0585cb9b8e9da6cb92ecb052a9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="qqzhq9qIk6xYZ24ic8AyIk5TTJYL2zI6pfhPKlGafE8cYveT4ITi1vodAxQxco5h06gg2M6N/F1opEvswl0xwQ==" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>New Question</h1>

<div class="row">
<form class="new_question" id="new_question" action="/questions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="5zxWU69klqpU0gKvE3hnIDdNuyB7wrY1nmoYUn5ojABXKR3IroJ4UpiD/P167VcyOKYg2wHiAGT6dGfh+N7ndg==" />
      <p>
        Body: <input type="text" name="question[body]" id="question_body" />
      </p>
    <p>
      Notes: <input type="text" name="question[notes]" id="question_notes" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Distractors
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="distractors">

    </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <a class="add_fields" data-association="distractor" data-associations="distractors" data-association-insertion-template="  &lt;div class=&quot;nested-fields form-control&quot;&gt;
        &lt;input class=&quot;distractor_body&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;question[distractors_attributes][new_distractors][body]&quot; id=&quot;question_distractors_attributes_new_distractors_body&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;input label=&quot;true&quot; type=&quot;radio&quot; value=&quot;true&quot; name=&quot;question[distractors_attributes][new_distractors][correct]&quot; id=&quot;question_distractors_attributes_new_distractors_correct_true&quot; /&gt;
      &lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;question[distractors_attributes][new_distractors][_destroy]&quot; id=&quot;question_distractors_attributes_new_distractors__destroy&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;remove_fields dynamic&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Delete distractor&lt;/a&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
" href="#">Add distractor</a>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Question" data-disable-with="Create Question" />
  </div>
</form></div>


<a href="/questions">Back</a>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the actual HTML (not erb templates) from the page.

Comment: Added the generated HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara doesn't support regexes for id or name attributes (and your example attempts actually show you passing strings not regexes anyway).  When dealing with dynamically generated elements the key is generally to scope your element locating via known elements that allow you to select a single element via class or other known attribute.  In your case the example HTML doesn't actually show an instance of the input you're trying to fill out, but assuming instances of the nested-fields templates are inserted dynamically into the `.distractors` div something along the lines of the following should work

```
find('.distractors .nested-fields:first-child .distractor_body').set(distractor_body) # use last-child, nth-child to select the correct section if multiple
```

When using this in your step with the need to 
choose the radio button as well it would probably be best to scope using `within`

```
Then(/^I fill the distractor field with "([^"]*)"$/) do |distractor_body|
  within('.distractors .nested-fields:first-child') do
    find('.distractor_body').set(distractor_body)
    choose('correct')
  end
end
```

Comment: Very much appreciated Cheers!